# In a task list, how do I get the ID number to start with 1?

Tags: 2010, column, site-column, task-list, id

I created a task list in SharePoint 2010 and would like the ID column to start with the number 1, instead of the number 7. The next number is 15.  Why is it not sequential. I am a novice.  How do I get the ID column to read 1, 2, 3, etc.?

Comment: The offset id happens, when you create and delete several items afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Save the list as a template and restore it from there.
Every time you restore that list, the ID will start back at 1. If you want to restore it in the same site, then delete the existing list (after you save it list as a template) and then recreate it from the template.

**Note: if you have custom permissions and/or lookup-fields in that list, you'll need to restore them.**